# Custom {fmt} formatting function with compile time format string checking

Tags: c++, fmt

I've got my own logging functions. I want to use libfmt to format the log parameters, eg:

```
log_error("Error on read: {}", errMsg);
```

However compile time format string checking seems to only work if I call the print/format functions directly, not if I call them in my log function:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

template<typename ...Args>
void log_error(fmt::string_view format, const Args& ...args) {
    // Log function stripped down to the essentials for this example
    fmt::print(format, args...);
}

int main()
{
    // No errors on this line
    log_error(FMT_STRING("Format with too few and wrong type arguments {:d}"), "one", 2.0);
    // Compile errors on the next line
    // fmt::print(FMT_STRING("Format with too few and wrong type arguments {:d}"), "one", 2.0);
}
```

The above code and the error (if second line is uncommented) can be seen on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ZqyU4X)

Is there any way to get this compile time format check to work in my own log function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the format string as another template to the custom `log_error` implementation. Example:

```
template<typename Str, typename ...Args>
void log_error(const Str& format, const Args& ...args) {
    fmt::print(format, args...);
}
```

This produces the same error as the direct invocation.

Comment: This no longer seems to work with fmt version 9: ‘format’ is not a constant expression